# How to create REST API on Servlet for authentication with access token

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, servlets, oauth

I want to create a **REST** API on Java **Servlet** for user authentication using simple **Oauth** and **JSON**. When the user login correctly, it will generate a unique **access token**. The token will be used as a representation of user session state. Then, the token will be used when the user access certain pages.

Can you give me an example or reference link?

Comment: Search on your favorite search engine "REST API on Java Servlet "

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this API that is used for security systems

http://shiro.apache.org/webapp-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/) project. This generator of Web application generate a backend with Spring MVC, Spring Core, Spring Security and Oauth Token.

Exemple of Web site generate by JHipster: http://www.tests-psychotechniques.fr